# Which datapool does Bought Bought use?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Since Salesforce Support does not answer this question my hope relies on you ;)

My Question: Does the purchase need to occur at the same time in the same call? Or not? [Thanks for rephrasing @EazyE]

Therefore i will present two datasets (or tracking calls).

Data pool 1, elements inside one conversion:

```
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"},{"item":"2","quantity":"1"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer1"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"},{"item":"2","quantity":"1"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer2"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"},{"item":"2","quantity":"1"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer3"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"},{"item":"2","quantity":"1"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer4"}}
```

Data pool 2, elements inside different conversions:

```
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer1"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"2","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer1"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer2"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"2","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer2"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer3"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"2","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer3"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"1","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer4"}}
https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/MID/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"2","quantity":"2"}],"url":"","user_info":{"email":"Customer4"}}
```

Which dataset will be used to determine the list of item 1 called BoughtBought_1 (inside the Admin panel of Recommendation Lists inside MC-Predictive)?

- Is it Datapool 1?
- Is it Datapool 2?
- Will both be used? If so, is there
  a weighting that dataset1 has more impact?

---

*Question ends here.
Additional Information about the information Salesforce Support has provided are listed below.*

---

Answer from SFMC Support until now:

- **Answer 2 (current):**

> "The whole thing works like this:
>
> When you buy an item, a track conversion code is triggered from your
> website (this is the collect code you should have implemented), so the
> product code at the time of purchase is passed to MC via this code.
>
> Then a purchase list is created (this is done automatically) and the
> purchased item is compared to this list and items from this list are
> recommended to the user.
>
> The list is created in Email/Web Rec > Reporting > Admin Tools >
> Lists.
>
> In this case, for example, you have a purchase list.
>
> Einstein Recommendations is designed to find the relationships between
> potentially millions of products, e.g. people who bought this also
> bought that, based on tracking data from many customer visits to a
> website. Based on the subscriber's previous website behaviour (views,
> purchases, etc.), it determines what to recommend at the time of
> opening.
>
> This recommendation is created based on the logic/scenario used in
> your email."

- **Answer 1 (oldest)**

> "When you buy an item, a track conversion code is triggered from the
> customer's website (this is the collect code they should have
> implemented), so the product code is passed to MC at the time of
> purchase via this code. Then a purchase list is created and the item
> purchased is compared to that list and items from that list are
> recommended to the user."

Comment: People who bought this item also bought these items. The purchase does not need to occur at the same time in the same call. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Simple: Yes i do. Is this just to verify the question or already an answer? ;)

Comment: It's both, seeking clarity if I understood your question correctly and also describing how the system works.The scenario doesn't require the purchase to happen in the same call.